# Drawing a String ArrayList in Java Applet

Tags: java, swing, list, applet

I'm simply trying to output a String ArrayList in a java applet.  What's the best way to go about this?  I'm unfamiliar with Applet formatting

Comment: Create a series of JLabels or use a JTable or use a JTextField. Checkout [How to create a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: I am surprised nobody mentioned **`JList`**!  It is *perfect* for this use..

Comment: BTW - Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have options. It really depends on what you're trying to achieve

- Use a `JLabel`. For this, your will probably want to use HTML to enter the strings, for multiple lines, as `JLabel` doesn't support the `\n` carriage
- Use a `JTextArea`
- Draw the Strings onto a `JPanel`

---

You want to just run through the [**Swing tutorials**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) though, if you're unfamiliar with these ideas. These are very basic principles. Check out the section [**Using Swing Components**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html)

Comment: You can do quite a lot of things with html and simple CSS rules in Swing, as peeskillet suggests.  Don't you ever think that your `JLabel` is a web browser, but with imagination, you can get a decent view for your applet

Answer (score 1):

Text needs to be drawn on a somewhat Component. So, assuming you're use JApplet (ie swing) you can use Jlavel, Jtextfield, Jtextarea, jtable....it all depends on your gui requirements